# Can DHIS2 provision users in advance and then have them log in using OAuth2?

Tags: authentication, users, dhis2, oauth

We are looking at using DHIS2 as the data mart/dashboard backend for an application we are built. Its great that it has OAuth2 built in which makes it easy for us to allow SSO for a user.

However is there a mechanism for us to automatically provision a user as well? The auth store is external to DHIS2. We would want to create the user and attach them to the appropriate org they belong to.

Answer (score 1):

Using the power of sitesearch on duckduckgo :)

[1.48.3. User account create and update](https://docs.dhis2.org/2.26/en/developer/html/webapi_users.html#webapi_users_create_update) gives the webapi format to create a user